# Does G1 garbage collector use the same region size for every region?

Tags: java, g1gc

Oracle's [Getting Started with the G1 Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html) tutorial says the following about region sizes with the G1 garbage collector:

> The heap is one memory area split into many fixed sized regions.
>
> [...]
>
> Region size is chosen by the JVM at startup. The JVM
>   generally targets around 2000 regions varying in size from 1 to 32Mb.

It's not clear for whether all region has the same size in a JVM or there could be regions with different sizes (for example, 1500 regions with size of 1MB and 500 regions with size of 2MB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the regions are of the equal size. The article [Garbage First Garbage Collector Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html) says:

> The G1 GC is a regionalized and generational garbage collector, which
>   means that the Java object heap (heap) is divided into a number of
>   equally sized regions.

The JVM aims to create about 2000 regions. Their acutal sizes depend on your minimum heap size.